# Deploy Cloudsuite benchmark using Docker swarm mode

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I want to deploy a benchmark, called cloudsuite, using swarm mode for leveraging its benefits in distribution between hosts. The case (explained [here](http://cloudsuite.ch/webserving/)) I am trying to use has 4 components:

- memcached server
- web server
- db server
- faban client

the way for deploying the benchmark that is explained in documentation, is by using `docker run`. For instance, for deploying the web server this command is used:

```
$ docker run -dt --net=host --name=web_server cloudsuite/web-serving:web_server \
  /etc/bootstrap.sh ${DATABASE_SERVER_IP} ${MEMCACHED_SERVER_IP} ${MAX_PM_CHILDREN}
```

As you can see, it has custom entry point and also some additional parameters. it is the same for other components. I have two questions regarding these situation:

1- Can I use services in swarm mode to deploy these containers? How am I supposed to give the entry point and parameters in the command for creating the service?

2- As I have understood so far, the services are for containers that provide long term services, like nginx or mysql server. but my last component, faban client, is not a long term thing. it just starts and sends some requests to other components and gather some results. And also I need to get those results out of this container too. Can it be also a service?

I've read documentation of docker, docker swarm and a lot of other posts about it, still I'm not sure whether I am understanding docker swarm correctly or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I could not find a way to use swarm mode to deploy the benchmark. So the first Question maybe still open.
How ever I found out about the second question. Since the client component of the benchmark is not a service, it is not a service and should not be implemented as one. Using docker swarm (not the swarm mode) it is easy to deploy an overlay network and run all components communicating to each other. You can check my [repository in Github](https://github.com/alirezaamiri/cs-web-serving) for the bash scripts of such deployment. However, to show how the client component should be run, I bring my line of code for it:

```
sudo docker -H :4000 run \
--network web-serving-network \
--name faban_client \
cloudsuite/web-serving:faban_client {WEB_SERVER_IP}
```